# Entity Framework Insert stored procedure in a loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to execute an insert stored procedure in a loop using Entity Framework, something like this:

```
var context = new Entities()
var items = context.GetAllItems().ToList();

foreach(var item in items) 
{
    // Other select and update procedures
    context.InsertProcedure(item.Prop1);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

but I am getting an exception.

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Anybody had this before?

Comment: This may happen if you have a select statement within your store procedure... do you have something like that?... if this is not the case there are 2 other options: Why do you need an 'Insert' sp if you are already using EF to map entities? Option 2. Have you considered the use of a TransactionScope ?

Comment: @DavidEspino There is a SELECT @@identity statement, I have to use the SP, its a reusable part used elsewhere, what is the transaction scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there is another exception, but looks like this exception is always thrown when there is a problem within the loop.

What I did is that I changed the return type of the stored procedure to None in Model Browser