# Entity Framework execute stored procedure in a loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to loop through a list and execute a stored procedure on every item in the list.

```
foreach(value in values) {
    Context.Database
        .ExecuteSqlCommand(
            "sp_ProcedureName @value1, @value2, @value3",
            new SqlParameter("@value1", value.value1.ToString()),
            new SqlParameter("@value2", value.value2.ToString()),
            new SqlParameter("@value3", value.value3.ToString()));
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

I tried to use the async method as well. But that didn't seem to work. Is there something I am missing. Or is it not possible to run a stored procedure inside a loop?

Comment: is something else, like other threads do something with your context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Insert stored procedure in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984421/entity-framework-insert-stored-procedure-in-a-loop)

Comment: @ArjunPrakash Yes, there are recorded instances that this error is missleading

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Just guessing: is values the result of a database call? have you tried `ToList()` to force it to load all data?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I don't know how you caught that with the information given but that was indeed the issue. Thank you. marc_s. I will take that advice thank you.

Comment: Cool lucky guess :) I will post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the db call to populate `values` has opened a transaction, stopping the inside call functioning.

Try using `.ToList()` in the call that populates `values` to preload all of the values first.

Comment: @Rainman answer will probably also solve this problem but it might eat up quite a few connections

Answer (score 0):

It could be better to create new `Context` instance for per execution;

```
            foreach (value in values)
            {
                using (var yourContext = new YourDbContext())
                {
                    yourContext.Database
                        .ExecuteSqlCommand(
                            "sp_ProcedureName @value1, @value2, @value3",
                            new SqlParameter("@value1", value.value1.ToString()),
                            new SqlParameter("@value2", value.value2.ToString()),
                            new SqlParameter("@value3", value.value3.ToString()));
                }
            }
```